# How to make a reference of or call a member function if that member function exists

Tags: function, object, kotlin, reference, member

I want to check that if a member function of a particular name exists on a object, if it does call the member function or make a reference of that member function.

Here I don't have type of the object, i.e. the object maybe does not implement any interface but has a member function cancel().

I used [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/check-to-see-if-object-has-a-function-variable/1927) method (reflection) to check if the member function exists, i.e. `if (object::class.members.any { it.name == "cancel" })` and when this statement returns true I am sure that the method does exist but compiler is still unsure that the 'cancel' method exist in the object or not

```
fun canceller(object: Any): KFunction<Any>?
{
    var canceller: KFunction<Any>? = null

    // check if object has member function 'cancel'
    if (object::class.members.any { it.name == "cancel" })
    {
        // make reference of that member function and return it
        canceller = object::cancel  //cancel is still not recognized as a member function and gives an error that "Unresolved reference: cancel"

        // or just call it now
        // object.cancel()
    }
    return canceller
}
```

I expect that canceller variable should be assigned to value.cancel(), but the compiler is unsure that cancel() function exist (with an error "Unresolved reference: cancel") in the object even after we supplied a check inside if statement

Comment: As one of the answers suggests, you can do this using reflection: instead of just checking for the existence of the relevant member, you can use that to make the call.  BUT I'd advise caution.  In my experience most of the time you want to use reflection, what you really need is to improve the design instead.  Reflection is slow, fragile, and can't be checked by the compiler.  For example, can't you arrange for the objects to impllement a common interface?  (That way, you know they'll have a method with the same meaning as well as the same name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not meant to be used like this. Reflection is something you use if you don't know at compile time what you are dealing with at runtime. Some examples:

- you need to use a type that's configured in some properties file (`Class.forName("someTypeString").newInstance()`)
- you have written an utility that extracts the contents of your object for debugging purposes
- you need to access code that isn't really visible to you (private fields that you can't easily access, but you need to)
- many more... but most of the time very special use-cases

Now what you have shown is a function reference (`object::cancel`). In order to use a function reference the compiler must know the type of `object` and the `cancel`-function must exist for that type. As `object` is of type `Any` and the `if`-condition is only relevant at runtime, the compiler does not know that there is a `cancel`-function available and therefore compilation fails.

Note that if you aren't doing anything special, you should rather check for a common type/interface. So for example, if your objects implement an interface `Cancellable` you could just change your code to something as follows:

```
fun canceller(object: Any): KFunction<Any>? {
  var canceller: KFunction<Any>? = null

  // check if object is of type Cancellable
  if (object is Cancellable) {
    // make reference of the Cancellable::cancel-function
    canceller = object::cancel  // smart-cast acting

    // or you could also call it directly: object.cancel()
  }
  return canceller
}
```

or probably you could just spare that function altogether and end up with something like just:

```
val someObj : Cancellable = ...
// somewhere later:
someObj.cancel()
```

Reflection is rather expensive and if you aren't entirely sure what it is useful for, you should not use it.

If you really knew what you were doing... then ok... it's of course also possible to call that function via reflection and if you ask for the existance of a function via reflection you also have to call it via reflection:

```
object::class.members.first {
  // note: I am using just the first function... if there are several, you need to check which one to use (parameter/type)
          it.name == "cancel" 
   }
   .call(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use reflections for this purpose.

myObject.javaClass.kotlin.members.any { it.name == "cancel" }

And the better way to express the idea of "object that has all the variables" is to define the interface and have all those object implemented

interface Achiever { val name: String }

Comment: object::class is actually a shortcut for object.javaclass.kotlin, that i'm using. Plus i already mentioned in the question that _Here I don't have type of the object, i.e. the object maybe does not implement any interface but has a member function cancel()._